# Ag-Grid Slow with Cell Renderers

Tags: javascript, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm using React based Cell Renderers to render out a Material UI component for 1 column. I've noticed it's incredibly slow even with little data (maybe 30 items), scrolling is really laggy.

Their docs say that using a Framework in Cell Renderers adds a performance hit but I thought it might be with a significant number of rows, this is less than 25.

Grid:

```
              <AgGridReact
                columnDefs={columns}
                rowData={data?.edges?.map(edge => edge?.node)}
                defaultColDef={{
                  ...{
                    filter: true,
                    sortable: true,
                    resizable: true,
                    editable: false,
                    headerHeight: 12,
                    cellClass: 'no-border',
                    suppressNavigable: true
                  },
                  ...options?.columnDefaults
                }}
                headerHeight={35}
                frameworkComponents={options?.frameworkComponents}
                quickFilterText={filter}
                {...props}
              />
```

columns

```
  const columns = [
    {
      headerName: '',
      width: 80,
      cellRenderer: 'RowActions',
      cellRendererParams: {
        handleClone,
        handleEdit,
        handleDelete,
        handlePublish,
        data
      }
    }]
```

RowActions

```
import React, { memo, useState } from 'react';
import { IconButton, Menu, MenuItem, Button } from '@material-ui/core';
import { Menu as MenuIcon, CheckCircle, Publish } from '@material-ui/icons';

export const RowActions = memo(
  ({ handleClone, handleDelete, handleEdit, data: { qaSessionId, status } }) => {
    const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);

    const handleClick = event => {
      setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    };

    const handleClose = () => {
      setAnchorEl(null);
    };

    return (
      <>
        <IconButton
          aria-label="more"
          aria-controls="long-menu"
          aria-haspopup="true"
          onClick={handleClick}>
          <MenuIcon />
        </IconButton>
        <Menu
          id="simple-menu"
          anchorEl={anchorEl}
          keepMounted
          open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
          onClose={handleClose}>
          {/* YOU CAN ONLY EDIT A DRAFT ITEM  */}
          {status !== 'production' && (
            <MenuItem
              onClick={() => {
                handleEdit(qaSessionId);
                handleClose();
              }}>
              Edit
            </MenuItem>
          )}

          {/* YOU CAN ONLY CLONE AN ITEM IN PRODUCTION */}
          {status === 'production' && (
            <MenuItem
              onClick={() => {
                handleClone(qaSessionId);
                handleClose();
              }}>
              Clone
            </MenuItem>
          )}
          <MenuItem
            onClick={() => {
              handleDelete(qaSessionId);
              handleClose();
            }}>
            Delete
          </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
      </>
    );
  }
);
```

As I scroll I visibly see the react components / cell renderers showing after a few seconds 
I also get: `[Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took <N>ms` while scrolling

Comment: can you provide an example on stackblitz or plinkr

Comment: You're going to have to profile your code to see where the bottleneck is. For reference, I'm using framework cell renderers with Angular, which I'm assuming is not any more performant than React, and I'm not seeing this problem.

Comment: Maybe this post will help you a bit (you will get a baseline for comparing your renderers): https://en.morzel.net/post/ag-grid-react-cell-renderers-performance

Comment: Ah, thanks for this update I'll take a look. We improved performance by disabling certain aspects of MaterialUI. Like ripples and keeping popup dom elements when items we're visible. This helped a lot.

Comment: Hi @batman, can you expand on "keeping popup dom elements when items we're visible"